# What are purple lines in edit mode?

Tags: uv, edit-mode

I know the red lines are seams. What are the purple lines?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the Edge Crease to control the sharpness of the edges when you use a Subdivision Modifier. you can control it in edge mode by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>[image]

Hope that helps.

Good Luck